# INDOOR Location Using GSM or 2G network for windows mobile

Tags: geolocation, windows-mobile, location, gsm, indoor-positioning-system

I was wondering how can i get my indoor location using GSM mobile data or 2G network on a windows mobile device.

If you could refer a Website/Application that can assist me..
Country: Lebanon
Device: Motorola MC55
OS: Windows mobile 5 and 6

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GPS will most times not work indoor. You may use the CellID and a database with the locations of the cell towers. OpenCellID offers such data for free (opencellid.org) and they also provide an API to query or update the database. This will give you a more or less acurate location based on the cell tower location information.

Josef

Comment: I just found an article I remembered at codeproject where they implemented opencellid.org (and others): DeepCast http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31965/Learn-How-to-Find-GPS-Location-on-Any-SmartPhone-a#6